# Can't see DVD-ROM drive on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, dvd

On my notebook I installed Ubuntu 10.04 today, but when loading it, I can't see the DVD-ROM drive.

What can I do? Are there any console commands to solve this issue?

Comment: **Which** notebook? This could be essential here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any other distributions? Ubuntu is famous for working perfectly but being a hassle to fix if it doesn't! That's a result of a generally user-heavy distribution with not enough advanced users in it.

You could give Debian a spin, it's very friendly.